# Resizing JavaFX Windows while maintaining aspect ratio?

Tags: resize, javafx, javafx-2

I have a window, which I have to keep square. My code is

```
 primaryStage.minHeightProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
 primaryStage.minWidthProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
```

It does resize the square when extending but has problems when I try to make it smaller?
Sometimes one of the sides gets a little shorter or longer than the other one. Is there a fix for this? Did I do something wrong in the code I currently use?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but I think is actually better UX since you don't restrict the user.  Instead of fixing the aspect ratio of the stage, consider using insets to pad the content you want to remain square:

```
private val DEF_PAD = 6.0
chart.paddingProperty.bind(boundValue(stage.widthProperty, stage.heightProperty) {
    // Maintain a square plot with padding
    val w = stage.getWidth
    val h = stage.getHeight
    val extra = DEF_PAD + 0.5 * Math.abs(w - h)
    if (w > h) {
        new Insets(DEF_PAD, extra, DEF_PAD, extra)
    } else if (h > w) {
        new Insets(extra, DEF_PAD, extra, DEF_PAD)
    } else {
        new Insets(DEF_PAD)
    }
})
```

(Written in Scala. `boundValue` is just a utility that creates a binding with a varargs dependency list)